# How to add div horizontally till width size exceeds?

Tags: html, css

I want to add tile horizontally until there is space available horizontally. Then it should automatically come to second line/row.

it should also be responsive to the different size of the screen.
My initial code is as below:

```css
.tile {
  width: 248px;
  height: 126px;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  margin: 17px;
}

.title {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 13px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile1</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile2</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile3</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile4</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile5</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile6</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile7</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile8</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile9</label>
</div>
```

I want Tile 1,2,3 in the first row then 4,5,6 in the second row and so on in a **responsive** fashion. (it's just example, Number of tiles in one row should be automatically adjustable(Tile size is fixed) to page width).

How to achieve this (without javascript)?

Comment: You need to float `.tile`, not `.title`.

Comment: that is only to adjust title. ;)

Comment: `display: inline-block` in `.tile` either you can use `float: left`

Comment: thank you @Girish, it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css file

```
.flex{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
align-items:center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex">
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile1</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile2</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile3</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile4</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile5</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile6</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile7</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile8</label>
</div>
<div class="tile">
  <label class="title">Tile9</label>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

USING THIS css it will make responsive as per your increase the width  and add the extra  `"<div class="flex"></div>"` please note this ...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using **flex-wrap** property in css which works even when you resize the browser window (**responsive**) as shown below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: green;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>Tile 1</div>
  <div>Tile 2</div>
  <div>Tile 3</div>  
  <div>Tile 4</div>
  <div>Tile 5</div>
  <div>Tile 6</div>  
  <div>Tile 7</div>
  <div>Tile 8</div>
  <div>Tile 9</div>  
  <div>Tile 10</div>
  <div>Tile 11</div>
  <div>Tile 12</div>  
</div>

<p>Try resizing the browser window.</p>

</body>
</html>
```